# Are Tor (Onion) addresses static or dynamic?

Tags: ip, ip-address, tor

I've yet to install tor on my server, but once I did, will my Onion address be static?
My gut feeling is that Tor links are bounded to an IP address (Mine is dynamic) and would act as such but I couldn't find anything to confirm or deny my theory.

Are Tor addresses static or dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are Tor (Onion) addresses static or dynamic?

I am going to assume you mean `.onion` addresses for any hidden services you are running.

In this case, it depends on whether or not there is an existing private key in your hidden services directory. This can either be:

- `private_key` for older 16 character onion addresses (a.k.a version 2 addresses)

or:

- `hs_ed25519_secret_key` for newer 56 character addresses (a.k.a version 3 addresses)

If either of these files are present (you have run Tor before with the proper hidden service lines in your `torrc` file or have placed them there yourself), then any resulting `hostname` e.g.:

```
someshortaddress.onion
```

or:

```
reallysuperextraextralongdidImentionhowlongthisaddressis.onion
```

will remain the same. If these private keys are missing, a new set will be generated automatically and the derived `hostname` won't be the same.

---

*A basic overview of how hidden services work from a technical standpoint can be found [here](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/onion-services.html.en).*

---

Answer (score 0):

Are you making a website on Tor? If so the IP address bounded to the URL will be static like the internet, but Tor does not use DNS to match IP addresses to URL's so it theory using Tor it will be heavily encrypted. If you disconnect your server then the router may change the IP address if as you said you think it's dynamic, you should be able to change that either in your router and/or server settings.

Comment: An IP address isn't bounded to a URL, it's more of the opposite. Also "bound" is misleading as it implied an attachment while it's in reality just pointing. As I said, my IP is dynamic and change every 2 weeks or so and, unfortunately, I cannot have a static IP without providing additional shekels to my ISP.